# (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80, Mac OS Lion

Tags: osx-lion, apache-http-server, port, ruby-on-rails, passenger

I was trying to get passenger to work on my home computer and ran into this problem.

I get this error when I try to start Apache.

```
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

I get Syntax OK when I test Apache.

this is where I set port 80 in my Apache config file.

```
 52 NameVirtualHost *:80

 53 Listen 80
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does [this](http://raduner.ch/blog/osx-apache-httpd-could-not-bind-to-address) help?

> 1. Go to my System Preferences.app and open “Sharing” pane. Disabling the Web-Sharing service.
>
>    [image]
> 2. Launch Terminal.app and stopping httpd (apache) with the following command:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apachectl -k stop
>    ```
> 3. Going into the Activity Monitor.app and searching for “httpd”. Select both processes and click on “Stop”.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Shutdown and start my Mac (do a proper shutdown, not restart!)
> 5. When Mac was back up running: go in to Terminal.app and execute:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apachectl -k start
>    ```

Answer (score 9):

The problem will be that you didn't start Apache as root - by default on any unix based operating system only root can bind a process to a port below 1024.

Your choices are to either use a port higher than 1023 and remember to specify it when you connect, or to ensure that you start Apache as root. Unfortunately not being a Mac user I can't provide details of how to do the second.